# Why Ctrl+P menu would be different, and no "Bone" option

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

On an empty project, when I select mesh and bone, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, I will see "Bone" in the menu.

[image]

Download a rig from online
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/284185/MinecraftPlayer.blend

And try to attach a weapon onto the rig
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/284185/Bow.fbx

**However when try to attach the weapon to bone (extrude right hand with extra bone), menu is now different. Any idea how to have the bone option show up?**

[image]

Comment: you select the mesh first and the armature last, the order of selection is important

Comment: for the first picture, your trying to attach a *mesh* to the bone. in the second, your trying to attach an *object* to the bone.

Answer (score 1):

That is referred to as a [context menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_menu), the available options vary depending on the active item that the action will be performed on. The active object is the one that will become the parent of the remaining selection, it can usually be identified by being highlighted in a lighter colour that the other selected objects.

In your first example you are parenting to an armature.

In the second example you are parenting to a mesh object (that is why you get the vertex parent options).

If you are parenting to a curve object you get curve options.

[image: curve parenting menu]

Parenting to a lattice you get lattice options.

[image: lattice parenting]

While if you parent to an empty or metaball object you only get simple object parenting options.

[image: empty parenting]